# Parallel using Android studio installed in a server

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-server

I have Android studio installed in my Ubuntu desktop machine. 
My friend and myself are App developers. 
Is it possible that both my friend and me connect to desktop as a server client mechanism and use Android studio from our laptops in parallel. 
That is, both use the same software at the same time. Maybe using VNC to login, create session and use from our laptops.

Comment: same software using different logins yes.

Comment: android studio provide SVN

Comment: How to achieve..   Kindly support